# How to access an Array of a Object in a Template in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, templates

I have an Object that has an array related to it. How do i access said Arrays values, in a Template?

Comment: You'll need to give us more info... What is your template engine ?

Comment: It's a custom Template, afaik.

I can access values with things like $(this.<object name>.<attribute>) but upon trying to do so on the Array objects that are bound to the Object, it tells me it's undefined, despite that i can see the attributes etc for them in the Console.

Comment: Well I'm not able to help without seing some code...